# OdbcDatareader parsing

Tags: c#, odbc

I'm having a weird problem. I have the following method:

```
    private static string getText(OdbcDataReader reader, string fldName)
    {
        string str = "";
        try
        {

           str = System.Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(fldName)));
        }
        catch { }
        return str;
    }
```

I have a product ID: 14-29aa

When I run string id = getText(reader,"ProductID");

id = 14-29AA

How do I keep the case when pulling the value? Looking online it says GetValue returns result in native format.. how do I stop this conversion?

EDIT: The field is a "Repeated Textfield" and the Database is Filemaker Pro

Comment: What's the field type in the database?

Comment: This _does_ keep the case. I suggest you re-check what value is stored in the database.

Comment: The value in the database is 14-29aa .. so I'm even more confused

Comment: Please post the code and query used to populate the reader. It could be something as simple as `SELECT Upper(Product ID)...`

Comment: I'm not doing anything like that. The query is simple "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE inStock=TRUE" and I'm iterating product IDs

Comment: But there is no way to know what you are calling as you are not providing the code retrieving the data, just an extension method where you think the problem may be